# Server configuration for virtual servers

Tags: security, virtual-machine, scalability

From what I'm aware, best practices regarding server configuration is to have a separate server for your web server and your database server. The web server would have the relevant ports (80 and 443) exposed to internet traffic, while the database server would be completely blocked from access for everything except for networked connections between the web server.

As far as I'm aware, there are three main reasons for doing this:

1) Any sort of attack that allowed someone to gain access to the web server would ideally not allow them access to the server which actually contained the data, so the data becomes more secure. Also, an attack that brings down the web server could theoretically be resolved by rerouting traffic to a different web server connected to the same database server, thus minimizing downtime.

2) Resources consumed by the web server are separated from those for the database server so, for example, a large amount of traffic on the web server would not slow down performance on the database server

3) The machines are somewhat more scalable, since, for example, if the problem ends up being that there is too much load on the web server, it can be upgraded independently of the database server

Can these same benefits be gained by using a single machine with two VMs installed on it, one for the web server and one for the database server? The third benefit is of course not possible, since there's only one physical server. But how about the first two?

It seems to me like the first benefit is still intact, since an attack that gains access to the web server would theoretically not allow similar access to the database server, and, as far as I'm aware, gaining access to the virtual machine does not provide access to it's parent physical machine.

The second benefit seems somewhat less relevant, since there is really only one pool of resources that are being split between the two machines, so in fact, it would probably be better to *not* split them, as it would allow a bigger pool to draw from.

Am I overthinking this? Is the fact that there is only one physical machine pretty much the end of the story, and splitting it into two separate VMs a complete waste of time and resources?

Comment: Having them running in separate vms -  and writing your code as if it were all on separate machines - allows you to migrate in the future much easier than coding it as if it were running all on one host.  Also, you can give the VMs different amount of resources, so some upgrading for a specific one is still possible based on host system resources....